# Identity Server 4 cant given grant Access

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, razor-pages

I am using Asp.net Core with a Razor page as a client working perfectly but when I try to deploy into Azure Identity Server it doesn't grant access to web clients.

Config.cs:

```
 new Client
            {
                /*
                ClientId = "mvc",
                ClientName = "MVC Client",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,

                // where to redirect to after login
                RedirectUris = { "http://myip/signin-oidc" },

                // where to redirect to after logout
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://myip/signout-callback-oidc" },

                AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile
                }
                */
                ClientId = "webapp2", 
                ClientName = "web with openid",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,

                ClientSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret("web123".Sha256())
                },

                RedirectUris           = { "http://myip/signin-oidc" },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://myip/signout-callback-oidc" },

                AllowedScopes =
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    "masterdataapi",
                    "transactionapi"
                },
                AllowOfflineAccess = true
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

its solved by me, i need to add authorize page in my startup.cs client